# Docker-compose run service in case of other failure

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to ask if it's possible to run some backup service in case of failure. My scenario is:

I have two ways of communication (default and critical), in case of failure the default, I want to start other service from docker-compose.yml.

I want to place both methods in the same docker-compose.yml file.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve such a case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the given docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  default:
    image: alpine
    command: sleep 10 && exit 1
  critical:
    image: alpine
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

You could get your desired effect by having a long-running process that waits for the "default" service to exit and then fire up critical once it sees exit code 1 (you can adjust the exact logic to fit your failure mode):

```
docker-compose up -d default
```

and then:

```
result=$(docker wait $(docker-compose ps -q default)); if [ $result -eq "1" ]; then docker-compose up -d critical; fi
```

The docker wait command will block until the "default" container exits and print the exit code, which goes into the $result variable. The logic after that checks for "1" and then brings up the "critical" service.

Comment: Thank you very much :), clever way with docker wait